# Is it possible to split Greasemonkey user scripts into multiple files?

Tags: split, greasemonkey

I'm creating a Grasemonkey user script that is getting really big.

Can I split it into several smaller files? If so, how?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, and in Greasemonkey, it's rather easy. If you want to split your scripts into `i18n.js`, a `utils.js` and your main script body (and had them in that order in the original script), just change your script header to read something like this:

***i18n.js***:

```
var hello = 'bonjour!';
```

***utils.js***:

```
function say(msg) { alert(msg); }
```

***my.user.js***:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           My nifty script
// @namespace      Your unique author identifier
// @require        i18n.js
// @require        utils.js
// ==/UserScript==

say(hello);
```

…and Greasemonkey will download and install all three files, join them up in the order listed by your `@require` statements (main script last), and execute it as usual. Put them in the same directory on the server you distribute them from, or be sure to give full URLs in the `@require` statements to where they reside on the net.

Comment: Must the required script be downloaded?  I just run UserScripts locally.  Can one UserScript include a js file by `@require`-ing another installed UserScript?

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can. For example, if you use Greasemonkey as Mozilla addon, then in `config.xml` you can use `<Require>`:

```
<UserScriptConfig>
    <Script filename="babelfish.yahoo.com.js" name="Babel Fish" namespace="html"  basedir=".">
        <Include>http://babelfish.yahoo.com/*</Include>
        <Require filename="document.js"/>
        <Require filename="cookie.js"/>
        <Resource name="babelfishCSS" filename="babelfish.yahoo.com.css" mimetype=""/>
    </Script>
...
```

Both `document.js` and `cookie.js` should be in the same folder as `babelfish.yahoo.com.js`.

If your engine uses in-file annotations, then use `@require` directive:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @description This script automatically recovers the language selection.
// @include     http://babelfish.yahoo.com/*
// @require     cookie.js
// @require     document.js
// @resource    babelfishCSS babelfish.yahoo.com.css
// ==/UserScript==
```

Comment: While none of the above is incorrect, `config.xml` is Greasemonkey's private implementation details, there is no need to poke around in there manually, and doing so anyway may cause all sorts of problems, the worst of which probably is Greasemonkey losing track of all your installed scripts.

Comment: If you know how to split scripts in smaller pieces without manual work − you are welcome to share your approach. Above advise works fine for me.

Comment: That's easy: Just cut it into separate files as you like, edit the main script to `@require` the other parts in the order wanted, and reinstall the main script (keeping the same `@name` and `@namespace` as it had originally).

If your original script didn't have a `@namespace` or `@name` specified, you probably also need to save it to the same URL as you installed it from before reinstalling.

Comment: sure but that again supposes that these scripts live on the internet, rather than just locally.